# mockito, spy- not sure how it's done for partial mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a class, where i want to mock certain methods of the class and test the others. That is the only way i can verity and assert that it's working.

```
class UnderTest{
   public void methodToTest(){
     methodToCall1()
     methodToCall2()
   }


  public void methodToCall1(){
  }

  public void methodToCall2(){
  }

}
```

Now, since i want to test the first method, i want to create a partial mock of UnderTest so i can verify that those two methods were called.
How do i achieve this in Mockito?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned you wanted to do two things:
1. [Create real partial mocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) 
2. [Verify method invocations](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)

However, since your goal is to validate that `methodToCall1()` and `methodToCall2()` were actually invoked, all you need to do is [spy on the real object](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13). This can be accomplished with the following code block:

```
    //Spy UnderTest and call methodToTest()
    UnderTest mUnderTest = new UnderTest();
    UnderTest spyUnderTest = Spy(mUnderTest);
    spyUnderTest.methodToTest();

    //Verify methodToCall1() and methodToCall2() were invoked
    verify(spyUnderTest).methodToCall1();
    verify(spyUnderTest).methodToCall2();
```

If one of the methods are not called, for example `methodToCall1`, an Exception will be thrown:

```
    Exception in thread "main" Wanted but not invoked:
    undertest.methodToCall1();
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package foo;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Spy
    private UnderTest underTest;

    @Test
    public void whenMethodToTestExecutedThenMethods1And2AreCalled() {
        // Act
        underTest.methodToTest();

        // Assert
        verify(underTest).methodToCall1();
        verify(underTest).methodToCall2();
    }

}
```